# How to send an email attachment over 4MB using Python & Microsoft Graph API

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

Been scrolling across the web including here on Stackoverflow and can't find an answer to my question so I was wondering if anyone knew how to help please. I am using Python and have managed to get the following code to work for my app. This app sends an email through my corporate O365 account. It works well, sends an email and have also made it works with small attachments (less than 4MB). Here it is:

```
from O365 import Account,MSGraphProtocol
client_ID = ''
secret = ''
credentials = (client_ID, secret)
protocol = MSGraphProtocol(api_version='beta')

account = Account(credentials,protocol=protocol)
m = account.new_message()
m.to.add('email@email.com')
m.subject = 'sCRIPT FOR AUTOMATION'
m.body = "This is a test!"


m.attachments.add('big_file.csv') #takes a list for multiple files. However, 4MB size limit.

m.send()
```

This is all well and good, however, I need it to work with larger attachments. I feel like I have tried everything I can think of to make it work, however, haven't had any success. I saw some documentation here that suggested changing the protocol to MsGraphProtocol & api version to beta (see https://pypi.org/project/O365/) which I tried without success. I have read a lot into this problem and it seems Microsoft is aware of it but they claim to have a solution which is to create an upload session and upload my larger file in chunks? I have no idea where to start with this. I tried looking at this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-large-attachments?tabs=http and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/attachment-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http. However, none of this documentation was written for Python programmers, let alone beginners/intermediate users so got lost fairly quickly. I kind of get the problem. The request can't be bigger than 4MB and therefore I need to iterate my upload. I have an understanding of for loops in python, however, I haven't found it particularly clear how to apply this documentation to my particular use case. If someone could help/has done something like this before in Python, please let me know! Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The proper way to do this is to put the file on a web site somewhere and send a link via email.  OneDrive, DropBox, Confluence; you must have access to a file sharing service somehow.  Sending a large file in chunks subverts the whole purpose of limiting the size of emails.

Comment: Adding a python code that i tried last time (below in the answer, as here the formatting is not get for the code).. check it out whether it works for you or not.

Answer (score -1):

Adding code sample:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );
var attachmentItem = new AttachmentItem{
AttachmentType = AttachmentType.File,
Name = \"flower\",
Size = 3483322 }; 
await graphClient.Me.Messages[\"AAMkADI5MAAIT3drCAAA=\"].Attachments
.CreateUploadSession(attachmentItem)
.Request()
.PostAsync();\n";
```

Comment: WTF this code prints C# code